# Camel Processor not working in a Splitter pattern

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel route which, when a bit simplified, it boils down to the following one:

```
<bean id="myProcessor" class="com.acme.MyProcessor" />
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route>
        <from
            uri="file:/home/inbox?fileName=file.txt&amp;noop=true" />
        <split>
            <tokenize token="@" />
            <process ref="myProcessor" />
        </split>

        <to
            uri="file:/home/outbox" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

To my surprise I have found that even if the Processor is being invoked, it is not able to change the single tokens. For example:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        String myString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(myString.toUpperCase());

    }
 }
```

In the end, the file produced with the tokens is not altered by the Processor. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your route like this:

```
<route>
    <from
        uri="file:/home/inbox?fileName=file.txt&amp;noop=true" />
    <split>
        <tokenize token="@" />
        <process ref="myProcessor" />
        <to uri="file:/home/outbox?fileExist=Append" />
    </split>
</route>
```

IMHO, you split your file, processed it with processor and don't have anything to do with the results.

Comment: Thanks it seems I have misunderstood the purpose of the Splitter. I mean the tokens need to be used within the Splitter context. I mean  they are not altering the Body of the incoming file from what I can see